# Free/Open-Source Archaeological Geophysics Program?

Tags: software-recommendations, plugins, archaeology

Does anyone know a free/open source software or a GIS plugin for working with archaeological geophysics data, especially for data from a magnetic survey (magnetic gradiometer map)?

Comment: What have you used so far? What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ArchaeoFusion](http://archaeofusion.com/) from the [Center for Advanced Spatial Technologies](http://cast.uark.edu/home/research/geophysics/archaeofusion.html). It appears to handle magnetic survey data. Free as of now, and has been for quite some time.

[image]